# I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax

Tags: c

Implement a C file with the name Simple.c. Its header file should look like:

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_H_INCLUDED
#define SIMPLE_H_INCLUDED

void linesWith(int c);

#endif // SIMPLE_H_INCLUDED
```

The function linesWith(int c) should:

Read all lines from standard input.

Write to standard output only lines that contain at least one occurrence of the character c.

Comment: So what is the problem? Can you write a function? Read a line of input? Write a line to output? See if a character is equal to some value? Then you're close. Otherwise as about the specific problem.

Comment: I am reading dennis ritchie's book on C :) I'm learning from it on how to print and use int and variables and some functions.

Comment: @Julia You have to attempt this yourself and fail then upload the code that isn't working. The section you have above is essentially asking someone to to do the whole thing. This community frowns upon that which may result in your question getting downvoted or closed by moderators.

Comment: Step 1: Read a _line_ with `fgets()`. 2)  Search it with `strchr()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
char vals[256];
scanf("%s",vals);
int len = strlen(vals);
for(int i=0;i<len;++i){
    if(vals[i] ==c){
        vals[len]=0;
        printf("%s",vals);
    }
}
```

Should do the trick.

Scanf (C), allows us to get a string (given by %s) from the console in a "blocking" manner (program will wait). It returns the amount of items in the entry.

Printf (C), allows us to write a string (given by %s) to the console in a "blocking" manner (program will wait). It returns the length of the writing.

Then, we need only "test" each character and should a match be found, we must print the string.

Comment: I'll take a go at it :) I'm learning c as an INTEREST on my own :) Thank you.

Comment: Good luck on your learning journey, programming is excellent fun and a great challenge :)

Comment: The answer is 100% correct. Don't down-vote if you can't program at all. It is also informative.

Comment: I'm really sorry :) I accidentally hit the down button! Still new to SO maybe.  Thank you :) How do you upvote back anyways? I'm trying.

Comment: Your reputation is not high enough to cause this issue. It is some other neigh-sayer

Comment: You only need to press on the up or down arrow to up/down vote :)

Comment: `scanf("%s",vals);` does _not_ read a line from standard input.  A line may include various spaced white-spaces and ends with `'\n'` or `EOF`.  `scanf("%s",vals);` may read multiple lines as it consumes leading white-space.